# create a gradient of size and color of the points in ggplot2 extending beyond the values present

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am building a plot whereby each point has a size and colour based on a linear gradient in two separate columns

```
df1 <- data.frame (x = c(1:10), y = c(1:10), pointSize = 1:10, pointCol = 1:10)

ggplot(df1, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = pointCol, size = pointSize)) + geom_point() +
   scale_colour_gradient(low = "steelblue", high = "yellow")
```

the maximum value in the table for columns encoding color and point size are 10. Can I change the gradient sizes so that it goes from say = 10 to 20?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, the colors will be based on the data and the low and high gradient.  Are you trying to add different colors? `scale_color_gradientn`

Comment: `scale_size_continuous(range = c(10,20))`? perhaps try to describe your ideal output, relevant to the current output, for clarification...

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer. I have two scatter plots and I want them to have the same point size scale, but I cannot plot them together (I already have too much faceting). So I have a problem, since in plot 1 the biggest size value is 10 and in plot 2 it is 20. But I want the size corresponding to size value 10 to be the same on both plots

Answer (score 5):

You can define the same size scale limits for both plots. Here's an example:

Sample datasets:

```
df1 <- data.frame (x = 1:10, y = 1:10, pointSize = 1:10, pointCol = 1:10)
df2 <- data.frame (x = 1:10, y = 10:1, pointSize = 11:20, pointCol = 1:10)
```

Plot without standardising the scale for size (we can see size 10 in plot 1 matches size 20 in plot 2):

```
p1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = pointCol, size = pointSize)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "steelblue", high = "yellow") +
  theme_bw()

p2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = pointCol, size = pointSize)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "steelblue", high = "yellow") +
  theme_bw()

gridExtra::grid.arrange(p1, p2, nrow = 1)
```

[image: plot1]

Now let's define the same scale limits for both:

```
size.limits <- range(df1$pointSize, df2$pointSize)

> size.limits
[1]  1 20
```

Add the scales for size to each plot (we can see now the two plots share the same size legend, and the largest point in plot 1 is the same size as the smallest point in plot 2):

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(p1 + scale_size(limits = size.limits), 
                        p2 + scale_size(limits = size.limits), 
                        nrow = 1)
```

[image: plot2]